# jQuery Ajax call not working 100% in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

Ajax call, which triggers twice if one card is moved onto another stack. There are many stacks. If the cards are changed around on the same stack, the call is triggered only once.

Ajax call sends an array of ids for each record/card that is repositioned. Then the method in the controller repositions them based on the sequence.

Somehow this process only seems to work about 3/4 calls.

```
   $( ".row" ).sortable({
     connectWith: ".row",
     handle: ".portlet-header",
     cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
     placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all",
     update: function (event, ui) {
       var data = { 
         'positions' : $(this).sortable('toArray', {attribute: "data-item"}),
             'dates' : $(this).sortable('toArray', {attribute: "data-date"}),
           'newdate' : $(this).closest('.row').attr("data-row-date") 
       } 

         // return ids in order
          $.ajax({
            type: "PATCH",
            async: true,
            url: "/ticket_board/reposition_cards.json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
         });
       }
     });
```

Sample params (drag-n-drop cards with order from jQuery sortable).

```
Started PATCH "/ticket_board/reposition_cards.json" for ::1 at 2015-05-14 08:25:38 -0500
Processing by TicketBoardController#reposition_cards as JSON
  Parameters: {"positions"=>["5", "8", "13", "1"], "dates"=>["2015-04-20", "2015-04-20", "2015-04-21", "2015-04-18"], "newdate"=>"2015-04-20", "ticket_board"=>{"positions"=>["5", "8", "13", "1"], "dates"=>["2015-04-20", "2015-04-20", "2015-04-21", "2015-04-18"], "newdate"=>"2015-04-20"}}
```

The controller method, to which the ajax call seems to work about 75% of the time.  This is critical for my client. I really need help.

```
  def reposition_cards

    dates = params[:ticket_board][:dates]
    positions = params[:ticket_board][:positions]

    if dates or positions

      # move job on the same stack
      if dates.size > 1 and dates.uniq.size == 1
        positions.each_with_index do |ticket_id, index|
          Ticket.find(ticket_id).update(calendar_order: index)
        end

      # move job to empty stack
      elsif dates.size == 1
          positions.each_with_index do |ticket_id, index|
            Ticket.find(ticket_id).
              update(calendar_order: index, calendar_date: params[:newdate])
          end

       # useless case
       elsif dates.size == 0
         nil

       # add job to another existing stack
       elsif dates.size > 1 and dates.uniq.size == 2
         positions.each_with_index do |ticket_id, index|
           Ticket.find(ticket_id).
             update(calendar_order: index, 
             calendar_date: params[:newdate])
         end
       end
     end
     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @tickets, status: :ok }
     end
   end
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? What do the errors look like when it doesn't work? Does it fail in the controller or is the controller sending an unexpected response back to the client?

Comment: It's amazing how I seem to find the answer just after posting the question.  If you look closely at the params, you'll see 3 unique dates, and the controller only recognizes 2. So I've changed the line from `dates.uniq.size == 2` to `dates.uniq.size > 1`

Answer (score 0):

From a comment above.

Sometimes I seem to find the answer just after posting the question. If you look closely at the params, you'll see 3 unique dates, and the controller only recognizes 2. So I've changed the line from `dates.uniq.size == 2` to `dates.uniq.size > 1`